# Splitter control in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to implement SAPUI5 splitter button/control  that accepts one Label and one button like Linked in. Like linked in when you add your skills, text display along with delete button. If you want to delete the text then simple click on delete button, it will delete (this is what happens in linked in).

I am also want to implement same thing using SAP splitter control but i am facing some layout issue. I have tried a lot to fix this issue but no luck.

Here is my code

In code there three splitters in total. Main splitter called oSplitterH that saves 0.....n sub-sublitters in its addFirstPaneContent.

The problem is it always display split button in vertical alignment rather than horizontal like linked in. I also changed the layout into Horizontal  but still displaying in vertical alignment.

Any suggestion?

```
var splitterLabel = new Label({
    text : 'Splitter ',
    width: '80px'
});
    var oSplitterH = new sap.ui.commons.Splitter("splitterH");
    oSplitterH.setSplitterOrientation(sap.ui.commons.Orientation.Horizontal);
    oSplitterH.setSplitterPosition("200%%");
    oSplitterH.setMinSizeFirstPane("20%");
    oSplitterH.setMinSizeSecondPane("30%");
    oSplitterH.setWidth("200%");

        //adding Labels to both panes

    var oSplitter2 = new sap.ui.commons.Splitter("splitterH12");
    oSplitter2.setSplitterOrientation(sap.ui.commons.Orientation.Vertical);
    oSplitter2.setSplitterPosition("10%");
    oSplitter2.setMinSizeFirstPane("10%");
    oSplitter2.setMinSizeSecondPane("10%");
    oSplitter2.setWidth("20%");

    var oLabel2 = new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Part1"});
    oSplitter2.addFirstPaneContent(oLabel2);   

    var oLabel2 = new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Part2"});
    oSplitter2.addFirstPaneContent(oLabel2);   

    var oSplitter3 = new sap.ui.commons.Splitter("splitterH13");
    oSplitter3.setSplitterOrientation(sap.ui.commons.Orientation.Vertical);
    oSplitter3.setSplitterPosition("10%");
    oSplitter3.setMinSizeFirstPane("10%");
    oSplitter3.setMinSizeSecondPane("10%");
    oSplitter3.setWidth("20%");

    var oLabe123 = new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Part3"});
    oSplitter3.addFirstPaneContent(oLabe123);   

    var oLabe1234 = new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Part4"});
    oSplitter3.addFirstPaneContent(oLabe1234);   

    oSplitterH.addFirstPaneContent(oSplitter2);   
    oSplitterH.addFirstPaneContent(oSplitter3);   

    createProfileMatrix.createRow(splitterLabel, oSplitterH, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code may help you.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
        <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_goldreflection">
        </script>
        <!-- add sap.ui.table,sap.ui.ux3 and/or other libraries to 'data-sap-ui-libs' if required -->

        <script>
                sap.ui.localResources("sapui5samples");
                var view = sap.ui.view({id:"idlinkedIn-label1", viewName:"sapui5samples.linkedIn-label", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
                view.placeAt("content");
        </script>

    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="list"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.css

```
 .tech-area{
            border:1px solid gray;
            border-radius: 5px;
            width:500px;
            height:300px;
            left:0;
            top:50;
            position:relative;
            overflow:scroll;
        }
```

SAPUI5 view file (didn't used controller file)

```
 var oLayout;
sap.ui.jsview("sapui5samples.linkedIn-label", {

    getControllerName : function() {
        return "sapui5samples.linkedIn-label";
    },
    createContent : function(oController) {
        // create a simple SearchField with suggestion list (list expander
        // visible)
        var oSearch = new sap.ui.commons.SearchField("suggestSearch1", {
            enableListSuggest : true,
            startSuggestion : 1,
            search : function(oEvent) {
                var techName = oEvent.getParameter("query");
                addTechnology(techName);
            },
            suggest : doSuggest
        });
        // Button for adding the technology if it is not listed in the available
        // technologies
        var oButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
            text : "Add",
            tooltip : "Add Technology",
            press : function() {
                var tech = sap.ui.getCore().byId("suggestSearch1").getValue();
                addTechnology(tech);
            }
        });

        // create a simple horizontal layout
        var oLayout = new sap.ui.commons.layout.HorizontalLayout({
            content : [ oSearch, oButton ]
        });

        // attach it to some element in the page
        oLayout.placeAt("content");
        oLayout = new sap.ui.commons.layout.HorizontalLayout("target");
        oLayout.addStyleClass("tech-area");

        // attach it to some element in the page
        oLayout.placeAt("list");

    }
});
// Help function to handle the suggest events of the search field
var doSuggest = function(oEvent) {
    var sVal = oEvent.getParameter("value");
    var aSuggestions = filterTechnologies(sVal); // Find the technologies
    var oSearchControl = sap.ui.getCore().byId(oEvent.getParameter("id"));
    oSearchControl.suggest(sVal, aSuggestions); // Set the found suggestions on
                                                // the search control
};
var technologies = [ "Java", ".Net", "PHP", "SAPUI5", "JQuery", "HTML5", "" ];
technologies.sort();

jQuery.sap.require("jquery.sap.strings"); // Load the plugin to use
                                            // 'jQuery.sap.startsWithIgnoreCase'

// Help function to filter the technologies according to the given prefix
var filterTechnologies = function(sPrefix) {
    var aResult = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < technologies.length; i++) {
        if (!sPrefix || sPrefix.length == 0
                || jQuery.sap.startsWithIgnoreCase(technologies[i], sPrefix)) {
            aResult.push(technologies[i]);
        }
    }
    return aResult;
};
var count = 0;
var arr = [];
// function for add the item to horizontal layout
var addTechnology = function(techName) {
    var elementIndex = arr.indexOf(techName);
    // conditional statement for adding the tech to the list
    if (elementIndex === -1) {
        count++;
        // create a horizontal Splitter
        var oSplitterV = new sap.ui.commons.Splitter({
            width : "120px",
            height : "30px",
            showScrollBars : false,
            splitterBarVisible : false
        });
        oSplitterV.setSplitterOrientation(sap.ui.commons.Orientation.vertical);
        oSplitterV.setSplitterPosition("60%");
        oSplitterV.setMinSizeFirstPane("60%");
        oSplitterV.setMinSizeSecondPane("40%");
        // label with dynamic Id
        var oLabel1 = new sap.ui.commons.Label("tCount" + count, {
            text : techName,
            tooltip : techName
        });
        oSplitterV.addFirstPaneContent(oLabel1);

        var oLabel2 = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
            icon : "img/delete.png",
            press : function() {
                removeElement(techName);
                oSplitterV.destroy();
            }
        });
        oSplitterV.addSecondPaneContent(oLabel2);
        sap.ui.getCore().byId("target").addContent(oSplitterV);
        // Adding the tech to the parent array
        arr.push(techName);
        // Emptying the search box
        sap.ui.getCore().byId("suggestSearch1").setValue("");
    } else {
        sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.alert(techName
                + " is already added to the list");
    }
}
// function for removing removed element from parent array
var removeElement = function(addedTech) {
    // Find and remove item from an array
    var i = arr.indexOf(addedTech);
    if (i != -1) {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Please make a note that I concentrated more on functionality rather than look and feel

Thanks,
prodeveloper